# How to install the FAB feature in karaf?

Tags: jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, floating-action-button

In the [FAQ page](http://fuse.fusesource.org/bundle/faq.html#How_do_I_enable_FAB_support_in_my_OSGi_container_) 
There is a action about *How do I enable FAB support in my OSGi container?*

But It does not work. 
The error message is:

```
Could not add Feature Repository:
java.lang.RuntimeException: URL [mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xm/features] could not be resolved.
Please verify that the feature repository URL is correct and that your network connection works fine.*
```

I have tried to find some solution from Google, and I have tried adding following repositories into `etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg`:

```
http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases
http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/
```

And I can make sure my internet proxy setting is right.

So, It seems the feature's repository is wrong. 
Could you help me to give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the repo URL `mvn:org.fusesource.fuse/fuse-fuse/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features` doesn't exist.

I didn't try it myself, but probably `fabric-bundle` is what you're looking for:

```
features:addUrl mvn:org.fusesource.fabric/fuse-fabric/7.0.1.fuse-084/xml/features
features:install fabric-bundle
```

Checkout the [features file](http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/fusesource/fabric/fuse-fabric/7.0.1.fuse-084/fuse-fabric-7.0.1.fuse-084-features.xml)